# Does fellowship replace PhD salary?

Tags: phd, funding, salary, belgium

I'm currently applying to PhD positions, and was also advised to apply for a fellowship, but don't I need a PhD supervisor first? Even if I do get it, does that mean it replaces the salary given by the lab/company?

Edit: Sorry for the lack of info, the country is Belgium, fellowship is FWO, though I'm also looking in other European countries, therefore there are also EMBO and Marie Curie fellowships, though I'm still enquiring about them.

Comment: What country? What field? These things vary widely.

Comment: We definitely need more information here :-)

Comment: It will be different from university to university, country to country. It may even be different in different departments in the same university. Check with the school you are applying to. Be very nice to the support staff such as the secretary of the department head. They can be very much help to you. And they will know the correct things for what to do about funding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for a PhD fellowship with FWO you first need to find a supervisor (called promoter here). Formally the supervisor needs to endorse your application, in practice it is recommend to develop the application in discussion with your prospective supervisor.

The amount of the fellowship will be the same as the net salary for a PhD student employed by the university on an assistant position, so indeed the fellowship is meant to replace any salary. When receiving the fellowship, you are also committing to basically full-time work on the research project (some time for teaching support is admitted).

For details check here:
https://www.fwo.be/en/fellowships-funding/phd-fellowships/

Comment: So that means I need to find a PhD first before applying, I understand, thank you